# Make a field's value fixed once assigned

Tags: java

```
class A {

    Object obj;

}
```

Say I have this class with the field obj. I want to make this field's value fixed  once assigned.

The problem is that I don't want to assign the value in the constructor thus I cannot make the field `final`. Then it came up with me another solution:

```
class A {

    Object obj;

    public void setObj(Object obj) {
        if (obj ==null)
            this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a better (more elegant) one.

Comment: Your implementation is not thread safe (though without reads or indication if the value has changed - it might not be an issue, but odds are, it will become one if you try to make your project scale better later on)

Comment: And what is supposed to happen if one attempts to set the field twice?

Comment: and please, refrain from calling classes `a`, it hurts the eyes of any java developer, since classes should start with upper case letter (strong java convention)

Comment: @fge Not sure yet. Maybe a exception or maybe not. The focus is the value not be changed.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet%28V,%20V%29. I would throw an exception is set a second time, or at least return a boolean as compareAndSet does.

Comment: Change your method to `public synchronized void setObj(Object obj)`

Comment: I would re-consider how much you "don't want to assign the value in the constructor" and find a way to do this instead.

Comment: Problem is here: "I don't want to assign the value in the constructor". Really ... believe me ... you want!

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'll think twice. But isn't this problem actually occuring somewhere. So I am still curious about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use functional programming idiom, and make sure your objects are immutable, by returning a new object.

The idea is the "new object" does not let you modify the field, and the "old object" is creating a new instance (and returning it) instead of simply setting the field, when asked to. This guaranteed your field is still `final`, and you can only change it once.

```
class B {
    private static class ValuedB extends B {
        public ValuedB(Object obj) {
            super(obj);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getObj() {
            return super.obj;
        }
        @Override
        public B setObj(Object obj) {
            return this;
        }
    }
    public B() { 
        this(null);
    }
    private B(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    private final Object obj;
    public Object getObj() { return null;/* or raise exception */ }
    public B setObj(Object obj) { 
        return new ValuedB(obj);
    }

}
```

Invoking with `myB = b.setObj(...);`

Draw back is of course if you already possess multiple references to an instance of `B`, only one will me modified, so if it is the case - this idiom might not fit.

---

For example, running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.getObj());
    b = b.setObj("asdf");
    System.out.println(b.getObj());
    b = b.setObj("qwerty");
    System.out.println(b.getObj());
}
```

will yield, as expected:

```
null
asdf
asdf
```

Comment: Interesting solution. It takes me minutes to understand it a little. So this class can only hold one field?

Comment: @bijiDango You can modify it, but if you want multiple "set only once" fields - it might become unscalable (though you might be able to wrap it to overcome it, didn't think about it)